# Why have so few women competed in F1?

Tags: formula-1, gender

The [list of women competing in Formula One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_female_Formula_One_drivers) is *extremely* short.

Since we are seeing women teams in a whole lot of sports nowadays, F1 remains an outlier. Unlike in other sports, there does not seem to be too much of a reason for women and men not to be racing together (as it has already been done). So the reasons for so few women competing in F1 has to be found elsewhere.

I am wondering if any kind of formal, scientific, or at least semi-professional study has been conducted that looks into the structural and cultural aspects of this question and tries to explore why women don't compete. I'm also interested in knowing if the FIA, Formula One Management, or individual teams are currently (or have tried in the past) to encourage more women to compete in the sport.

Comment: Given F1 is not a sport where physical strength is relevant, this line of inquiry doesn't make any sense.  Take it up in [chat] if you want.

Comment: @Joe I wouldn't say that. Formula One cars are extremely physically demanding, due to the sheer amount of G-force they're able to produce while accelerating and cornering. It takes 100kg of force *just to operate the brake pedal*.

Comment: Not really appropriate for comments here, but that's a great argument for why women should be *dominant* in F1.  In high endurance required sports (which the G forces would qualify as), women outperform men.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such studies, but I can point to one piece of action the FIA has taken to encourage more women to enter motorsport: [the creation of the W Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_Series_(championship)).

Founded in 2019, the W Series is a women-only spec series using Formula 3 machinery. It is intended to act as a stepping stone for female drivers, allowing them to progress from the W Series up into feeder series such as Formula 2. Jamie Chadwick, the winner of the first two W Series championships, is currently a test driver for the Williams F1 team, but has yet to compete at a race weekend.

Comment: One thing about the W-Series is that it is free to enter - meaning drivers are there purely on talent - thus removing what would probably the main barrier to entry to getting into Formula 1 for most people (let alone women): Money